# How to use virtual functions of derived functions with different set of inputs from a base method in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a base class A, which does some preliminary stuff. There are 2 subclasses B and C, whose behaviours are slightly different from each other. There is a function in A say `foo`, which is almost the same for both B and C, except one little step, which involves a function call to `bar`. `bar` is virtual in A and has definitions in B and C. The problem is `bar` has an extra input in C. How do i handle this in the most acceptable and clean way ?

```
class A {
public:
       A( int a, int b );
       ~A();
       void foo( int a, int b );
       virtual void bar( int a, int b );
};

class B : public A {
public:
      B( int a, int b );
      ~B();
      void bar( int a, int b );
};

class C: public A {
public:
      C( int a, int b, int c );
      ~C();
      void bar( int a, int b, int c );
}

void A::foo( int a, int b )
{
    // Some code
    bar( a, b );
    // Some code
}

A::A( int a, int b )
{
    // Some code
    foo( a, b );
    // Some code 
}
```

The constructor and only the constructor calls `foo` which inturn is the only function that calls `bar`. I understand functions with a different signature than the base class doesnt override the virtual function in the base class. One way of doing it, is to have `c` as an argument to `A::foo` and `A::bar` also, but i want to avoid doing it, since `c` wont make much sense in case of `B`. Is there a better way of passing `c` cleanly to `bar` ?

Edit:

To give some context, class `A` is a FileReader class which reads from a file, and stores it in a `vector<unordered_map<int,int>>`, where every index in the vector corresponds to a record.

For class `C`, instead of having just a single `vector<unordered_map<int,int>>`, it was decided that it would be better if we had a `vector<unordered_map<int,int>>` and a `vector<size_t>`, because multiple records in the input, now belong to the same entity. Here every index in the first vector correspond to the `entity` and not the `record`. And the second vector maps the `record` to its corresponding `entity`. To find which records belong to which entity, there is an external input in the form of a big structure `c`, which maps one field of the record to the entity.

Class `B` was originally just class `A` itself. But now since there are 2 different behaviors of the similar thing, I decided to create a separate derived class for that, and make `A` a template.

Comment: Why do you want to inherit `B` and `C` the virtual `bar` method from `A`? Its not because `B` and `C` have a common interface and a user can use the classes polymorphically. What else is it ?

Comment: When you override a function in a child-class, I recommend you use the `override` special identifier to mark such functions. Like for example in the `B` class declare `bar` as `void bar(int a, int b) override`. Then the compiler will be able to give you errors when the override declaration doesn't match the parent class virtual function declaration. If you did that on `C::bar` you would get such an error, because it ***doesn't*** override `A::bar`. Instead it's an *over**load***. As such it's a totally different function.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `bar` method is a small part of the `foo` method which happens to differ between `B` and `C`. Everything else that `foo` does, is the same. `B` and `C` are pretty much the same thing except for a single internal data structure, which the function `bar` handles.

Comment: @HarishGanesan that doesnt make sense. If `foo` is the same and implemented in the base, then it either calls `bar(a,b);` or it calls `bar(a,b,c);`. The base class doesnt know about the child classes. There is a deeper problem with your design. I suggest you to read about the template method pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), and for the question it would help if you explain the motivation as this seems to be a xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It doesnt have to be passed through an argument. Since the extra input always comes through the constructor, i can even have it inside the class as a data member also. But since `c` isnt directly owned by the class `C`, I was reluctant to do it that way.

Comment: ". Since the extra input always comes through the constructor, " then I do not understand the quesiton. Simply do not pass it as argument to `bar` and the problem is gone, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But the `bar` function in `C` needs that extra input, where the `bar` function in `B` doesn't.

Comment: @HarishGenesan why does it need that input when it was already passed to the constructor?

Comment: i think adding a dummy implementation of the methods would help to clarify. Even something super simple would clarify. Currently its not clear what parameters are coming from where and are needed where, but it seems that the whole issue is to sort that out

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have added an explanation in the question. I wasnt sure how to share the implementation details, since it involves a lot of unnecessary stuff. Eventhough it was passed to the constructor, the aim of doing that is to use it for `bar`, which the constructor calls through `foo`. But as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74625953/7075416) explains, virtual functions dont work as expected in constructors. So i have to think of other ways.

Comment: "The problem is bar has an extra input in C. How do i handle" you don't. A virtual function is a *contract*. The contract says (at the very least) "I promise to accept parameters of types exactly A B C and return a result of type Z". If you inherit from a class that specifies a virtual function, you must fulfill the contract. There are no ifs or buts or maybes. If you want to fulfill a different contract in addition to that, fine. Just don't give it the same name to avoid confusion.

Comment: @n.m. I got that. Maybe i phrased it terribly in the question, but I was more interested in a way to pass that input _somehow_. It need not be an argument to the virtual function.

Comment: Have two functions with different names tat accept different inputs. If you know what input to pass, you also know what function to call. If you don't know what input to pass, then you are asking a wrong question. Ask not how to pass input, but how to fix your design.

Comment: @n.m. Actually the question was how to fix my design or more precisely, how to make a functioning design with these criteria. I may have confused people by saying the word "input". I didnt mean "input" to be a parameter strictly. I just meant that it is necessary for creating the structure inside `C`. The problem with having different names that accept different inputs is, I would end up duplicating a lot of code, which is essentially the same.

Comment: In order to fix a design we need to see a design. "A calls B, B calls C" is not a design. What the classes do? What these parameters mean?

Comment: @n.m. I have made an edit in the original question trying to explain what the problem in words. I am afraid I cant share detailed code here.

Answer (score 3):

Calling virtual function from the constructor may not do what you expect. In a constructor, the virtual call mechanism is disabled because the derived class gets created last. The objects are constructed from the base up. You can find more details here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors

In this particular case class A implementation of bar() would get called instead of class C implementation of bar().

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and saved me from hours of head banging. But in any case, even if this wasn't in a constructor, do you think there is any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained, that's not directly possible directly with your design. Firstly, as Rama said, a virtual function call from a constructor of a base class will call the base class function, not the derived class function.

Secondly, you are writing

```
void A::foo( int a, int b )
{
    // Some code
    bar( a, b );
    // Some code
}
```

this call already lacks `c`, where you are going to take it from?

---

What you should do depends on your particular situation. Following your explanation about reading from file, I would first think about a simple visitor-like pattern. As I understand, both your classes read the same data (a sequence of records), but then store it in a different way. So let the base class read raw records, and pass each record to derived classes, and let derived classes do the processing they need. Something along the lines:

```
void A::readAll() {
    int a, b;
    while (file >> a >> b) {
        // a, b is the raw record as stored on disk
        processRecord(a, b);
   }
}

void B::processRecord(int a, int b) {
    data_[a] = b;
}

void C::processRecord(int a, int b) {
    size_t entityId = vector_.size();
    vector_.push_back(b);
    // now vector[enityId] == b
    data_[a] = entityId;
}
```

In this case, you probably don't even need inheritance. Have a separate class (`A`) for reading file, have separate classes (`B` and `C`) for processing data, and either store a processor pointer in `A` (in this case you will probably need a base `Processor` class that is inherited by `B` abd `C`), or store `A` pointer in `B` and `C` (this will require reworking `A`'s interface).

At the same time, if, for example, you file stores `a`, `b` *and* `entityId`, then you should read all three values and pass them both to subclasses, and just ignore `entityId` in `B`.

Comment: The solution you propose might work. I assume `vector_` is the map from record to entity ID, i was talking about. In that case, my question is how i would get `vector_` without passing it as an attribute ? If the answer is that I could store it as a class attribute of `C`, I have already mentioned thats a possible solution in another comment, but I was worried that the object doesn't own the map, so storing it as an attribute wont be right, technically.

Comment: I should be stored in `C`, of course. If `C` does not own it (but why?..), then pass it to `C` as a pointer or as a reference.

Comment: For now, that's the solution I have gone with, I have stored it in `C` as a pointer. It is not owned by it, because it is built by another class, and these classes just use it to rearrange the records properly.

Answer (score 1):

So some kinds of FileReader need additional data, and others don't. Now the question is, where is this additional data available?

1. Where the specific FileReader is created. Then you pass the additional data to the constructor, and keep it in the object. If ownership is a problem, make it a copy, make it shared, or make sure that the owner of the additional data outlives FileReader.
2. Where FileReader::readFile is called. Then you pass the additional data to FileReader::readFile *and make the base class and all derived classes aware of it*. Implementations that don't need it may simply ignore it.
3. But (2) immediately follows (1), they are in the same function! Then you are not really using inheritance based polymorphism as intended. Everything is static and known at compile time, nothing needs to be virtual. You can ignore it and still go with (1). Alternatively, move to static polymorphism (templates, CRTP, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really understand why you pass things through parameters of bar. You have already passed them through the constructors. You can change the bar signature to void bar(); and use a,b,c like class attributes.

Comment: Yeah, that is one option. But then, the object doesn't own any of a,b and c. So it felt wrong to have it inside as class attributes.

Comment: well, another option:
`void bar(BaseParams *param);`
or maybe you should refactor you code using design pattern like visitor or strategy